# Mysql - 1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using Password: Yes)

Tags: mysql

I have installed MYSQL 5.6 stand-alone on a local windows server. Recently, I changed the local IP of my server and reconfigured it in my network, but now I am not able to access my databases. It is giving me this error:

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using Password: Yes)

The above error is coming while using localhost as the server name. Also, I am able to connect to localhost through root username, but it is not showing me the original DB's which I had before.

Also before the server IP change I was able to access the MySQL server through the old IP of the server. like host name: xx:xx:xx:xx , user: user, pass: pass .... But it is also giving me an error:

> 2003 - cannot connect to my sql server on 'xx:xx:xx:xx' (10038)

I have tried the solution define on following link and run following query: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.6/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('test');

and this is starting giving error of access denied for the root username and password 'test'

Can any body help me to resolve this.

Comment: connect to 127.0.0.1 as root. Execute `use mysql; select * from user where user='root';`. Update IP address for the row with old IP address.

Comment: could You explain - what happens when nYou connect as root@localhost? what are You can select/create and etc? it possible if You to grant permissions or create new user?

Comment: #a_vald. I am able to select/create from three dB's. But i have 15 to 20 db's which is not visible to me and also i have not accessed on that DB's. It is not allowing me to grant permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to 127.0.0.1 as root.

Update IP address for mysql user row with old IP address.

```
use mysql; 
update user set host='NEWIP' where host='OLDIP' and user='root';
flush privileges;
```

Try again to connect.

If you don't have root access, reset permissions and try again.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: it is not allowing me to update the user table of mysql. I have not access on mysql database using the root user.

Comment: You say: "Also i am able to connect to localhost through root username."

Comment: try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.6/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

do this only change root@localhost to root@% and then connect to server ip (not to localhost)

Comment: yahh.. but it is not showing all database. Also i am not able to access others through cmd.

Comment: try to reset password BUT not for root@localhost - it not help, this user not have permission (some time it do for security reason). try to reset for root@%  and than try to connect to server using server ip (not localhost)

Comment: i am facing error of timestamp with implicit default value is deprecated error.

Comment: I think better idea - edit question with all done steps, and all errors which You meet (better with copy text of error)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem experienced by people who downloaded the recent version (i.e MySQL 5.7.10)

The problem is there is a temporary password for this version

after you typed in  bin>mysql -u root -p  ...

you have to type in the password which is different for every person who downloaded it. Go to your mysql directory in C (or wherever you extracted it to) , go to the file 'data'. There would be an ERR file with your computer's name on it.

Open that file using notepad 
in the 6th line of commands, there would be a line as follows

[Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: '(your password)'

copy that password and paste it in the command prompt ... From there on you can continue as shown in the video

Answer (score 0):

Add the location where MySQL server is installed to an environment variable and that error will be gone as fast as it came setx PATH

```
"%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
```

You also want to make sure the command line interface is run as an administrator before you can run that cmd