# update database in data directory of mysql 5.6 to mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

For some days i am facing following error in `mysql 5.6.` which is not able to resolve.

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using Password: Yes)

I have posted it but not able to resolve it through provided answers. 
[Mysql - 1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using Password: Yes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899387/mysql-1045-access-denied-for-user-userlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Now i have backup my data folder and `uninstall 5.6` and `install 5.7.` Can any one let me know how can i add the databases from old data folder to `mysql 5.7`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve it. I am facing two problems.

- Access denied problem (1045 error)
- install mysql 5.7 and was unable to recover database from old mysql 5.6 data folder.

Here is the step which recover from old mysql 5.6 data folder which i have followed to fix this. 
- backup the mysql 5.7 data folder. 
 - Copy all database from old data mysql5.6 data folder to new mysql5.6 data folder. 
 - copy all ibdata files from old data mysql5.6 data folder to new mysql5.6 data folder.